# Function appending list elements to another list returning empty lists/tuple

Tags: python, list, function, tuples

I have a text file with three lines, which I split into a list of lists called `cleanedFileList` using `function1()`:

> hello, 1
>
> again, 2
>
> world, 3

which  after running through `function1()`, looks looks like this when printed, this is what printing `fileOutput` gets:

```
[[hello, 1], [again, 2], [world, 3]]
```

I'm essentially trying to create a `function2()` that can append the words in `cleanedFileList` into three separate lists based on the number value in the second position. For example, `[hello,1]` would be appended as *'hello'* to `l1` because it carries the value, 1, in it's second position in `cleanedFileList`... Likewise, `[again, 2]` would be appending as *'again'* to `l2` because of the value 2, in it's second position

```
fileInput = open('keywords.txt', 'r')


l1 = []
l2 = []
l3 = []


def function1(file):
        cleanedFileList = []
        for line in file:
            cleanedFileList.append(line.strip().split(','))
        return cleanedFileList

fileOutput = function1(fileInput)    

def function2(file):
       for i in range(len(file)):
            if file[i][1] == 1:
                l1.append(file[i][0])
            if file[i][1] == 2:
                l2.append(file[i][0])
            if file[i][1] == 3:
                l3.append(file[i][0])
       return l1, l2, l3


listOutput = function2(fileOutput)
print(listOutput)
print(l1)
```

When I run the code above however, I get an empty tuple (from the return statement in `function2()` and an empty list (from trying to print `l1`):

```
([], [], [])
[]
```

Comment: What is the output from the `print(fileOutput)` line?

Comment: Daniel , this is the output: [['hello', ' 1'], ['again', ' 2'], ['world', ' 2']]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, you have strings in fileOutput, not integers. So "1" != 1.
And also you can see space in your strings: ' 1', ' 2', etc.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to store elements into a dictionary than dynamically creating lists.

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [['hello', '1'], ['again', '2'], ['world', '3'], ['good', '1'], ['morning', '3']]

d = defaultdict(list)

for x in lst:
    d[x[1]].append(x[0])

print(d)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'1': ['hello', 'good'], '2': ['again'], '3': ['world', 'morning']})
```

Now, you can access all `1` elements as `d['1']`, all `2` elements as `d['2']` and so on...

For example:

```
>>> d['1']
['hello', 'good']
```

Comment: I continue to get an empty list when I run this with my code

Comment: @CosmicCat, Can you try splitting by `', '`, instead of `','` when you append to `cleanedFileList` ? That will split into `'1'` (not `' 1'`) which is more reliable. Then try running this code.